# Drupal.settings.mymodule is not an object

Tags: javascript

I have implemented a hook_menu() with a callback to check user's privileges and a page callback to create the html. When I am in page_callback(), I retrieve a JSON string from a db and I'd like to pass this string to a JS script that will do some visualization.

```
function page_callback( $id ){
    $myjson = mymodule_query($id);
    $vars = array('key' => $myjson);
    drupal_add_js(array('mymodule', $vars), 'setting');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/js/myjs.js');
    return '<div id="graph-data"></div>';
}
```

In the JS file, I have:

```
(function($){
    Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
        attach : function(context, settings) {
            if(Drupal.settings.mymodule.key !== ''){
                alert('Got it!');
            }
        } 
    };
}(jQuery));
```

When I try to execute this code, I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Drupal.settings.mymodule.key')
```

Is there any other way in D7 to pass a php variable at runtime to a JS script?

EDIT: trying to follow the advice using render arrays, what is the best way to translate my code? Here's what I have:

```
function page_callback( $id ){
    $output_data = array(
      '#theme' => 'graph_data', // not sure here...
      '#vars' => array('key' => mymodule_query($id)),
      '#attached' => array(
         'js' => array(
              drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/js/myjs.js',
         ),
         'css' => array(
              drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/graph_data.css',
         ),
      )
    );
    return $output_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => $vars), 'setting');
```

But ideally you'd be using a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/render-arrays/render-arrays-overview) instead, and loading the settings/files into the page with the [`#attached`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/managing-javascript-in-drupal-7#attached) method.

Comment: doh... I'll look for render array again, I did not understand how to obtain this same result that's why I opted for drupal_add_js()... my JS will use D3 to visualize a graph in a svg that I wanted to append to my div.graph-data

Comment: I have just edited my question, maybe you can check my attempt to use render array... thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use a render array instead (according to Clive's suggestion):

```
function page_callback( $id ){
  $setting = mymodule_query($id);

  // Ideally you should check if something exists:
  // This example returns 404 if no settings found for $id.
  if (empty($setting)) {
    return MENU_NOT_FOUND;
  }

  return array(
    // You can also convert this markup to a theme and use #theme,
    // or you can also return an empty #markup 
    // and use #prefix and #suffix to supply the wrapper.
    '#markup' => '<div id="graph-data"></div>',
    '#attached' => array(
      'js' => array(
        array(
          'type' => 'setting',
          'data' => array('mymodule' => array('key' => $setting)),    
        ),
        array(
          'type' => 'file',
          'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/js/myjs.js',
        ),
      ),
      'css' => array(
        drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/graph_data.css',
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: albeit I get again the TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Drupal.settings.mymodule.key'), should I also change something in the JS?

Comment: what I see is that data is passed to Drupal.settings.key and not Drupal.settings.mymodule.key

Comment: Ah, sorry, this was just untested pseudo code, hoped it would make sense to you so you can edit it yourself. Fixed the `setting` JS's `data` array to match what you wanted. Check the edited answer.